# why will one user account of three not log-in?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, login

Our family has three user account in /home.
I have just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and two of the three log-in to xorg OK but the third just cycles back to the log-in screen (gdm?) Mine, of course :(

Is there a log file I can s\check to find out why the third user account is cycling back to the beginning?  I can log-in fine to a virtual terminal, it's just xorg that is the problem, so I presume it is something in my home directory that should be deleted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've made same expierence, if the home folder and file permissions are changed due to a complete deletion/modifications an recreation.

Please press Ctrl+Alt+F1 -> login with the "problem (3rd)" user.

On command prompt:
chown -R $USER /home/$USER

Then press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and try to login with user again.